# XML gradient not starting at transparent as it's set to in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is my drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:endColor="#44000000"
        android:angle="90" />
</shape>
```

Here is my view that uses this drawable as it's background (in order to display a shadow under my toolbar):

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow"/>
```

Here is how it ends up looking:

[image]

As you can see, the gradient starts at some grayish color because there should be no gray visible -- the start color declared in the drawable is *transparent*. Correct me if I'm wrong, but what should be seen is the darkest part of the shadow under the toolbar, and from there it should get less and less dark, and more and more purple. If that's not what should be happening, any idea how I can make that happen?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the screenshot, you have three views in sequence: the toolbar, the shadow view, then the background view. The view with the shadow seems to not be overlapping the background view, that's why their colors don't blend.

What you should do is anchor both the shadow view and the background view beneath the toolbar. That way the shadow view's background will overlap the background view and blend properly.

Comment: the reason they don't seem to be overlapping is because the shadow view is not transparent as it should be. they *are* overlapping.

Comment: @shoe I've built a sample activity with the _exact same_ gradient and view, and the gradient blends fine with the view beneath it. Unless you've found a bug in some specific version Android (which I doubt), your gradient and view are absolutely correct. Which means the problem is with your layout.